# Issue with Unicode characters in photoshop javascript code

Tags: javascript, utf-8, special-characters, layer, photoshop-script

I have created a JSX for reading the data from TAB delimited input file (input file has two columns; ID and description). I want to read the input file and place the description on text layer and save the filename with ID.

It works when the description field letters and numbers. But it does not work when it has (é) in the description.

```
var Description = "on the ***pavé***";
  textlayer.textItem.encoding = "UTF-8"; 
        textlayer.textItem.contents = Description;
        textlayer.textItem.tracking =50;
        textlayer.textItem.wrapBend=70;
        var saveFile = new File(outputfolder + "\\" + ID + "_16.psd");
        saveFile.encoding="UTF-8";
app.activeDocument.saveAs( saveFile, saveOptions, true );
```

Comment: _But it does not work …_ Please [edit] your question to elaborate this vague assertion in your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF

var outputfolder = "C:\\temp";
var description = "pavé_16";

var mySaveFile = outputfolder + "\\" + description + ".psd";

var psdFile = new File(mySaveFile);
activeDocument.saveAs(psdFile, SaveDocumentType.PHOTOSHOP, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);

displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL
```

Are you sure you're saving out as `pavé_16.psd` and not `***pavé***_16.psd`? As asterisks (stars) in your filename will not work :)